# How to display three values fields and a target on a PowerBI visual?

Tags: data-visualization, powerbi, business-intelligence

I would like to display data on PowerBI considering the following datasets :

- Sales recorded and checked (RECORDED)
- Sales that are finalized but not recorded (IN PROGRESS)
- Sales that are hoped to be finalized soon (PROJECTED)
- The target of total sales for the current year

Here is what it's expected :

[image: gauge expected]

In a first time, I have tested the radial gauge. It's looking pretty good but I can't add more than one value and I would like to display all the datasets on it. 
It seems that it's not possible : https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Radial-Gauge-charts-with-two-value-fields/td-p/52727

So I have tried the cumulative graph but it doesn't have a target field.

Then I have played with the bullet graph but the issue is the same than the radial gauge.

So do you know how to display three values fields and a target on a PowerBI visual ?

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly what you're asking for, but you can get the same idea using a stacked bar chart.

[image: Bar Chart]

To duplicate this, use `Target` as the Axis, `Status` as the Legend, and `Values` as the Value:

[image: Source Data Table]

Comment: Thank for your answer Alexis, even if it's not exactly what I was searching it's a good solution and that's helped me a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a need without a perfect solution yet. I also have an "actual" value to compare against three "goals" and the gauges that are in the marketplace does not quite do the trick so I created line and clustered column chart. The column value is the "actual" and the three "goals" are line values. The three goals show up as a small circle by default but I changed it to a line by going to Shapes and change the marker shape to a line and size 15. I also had to turn off the secondary Y-axis.